# Is there any way I could run Raptor in macOS with an Apple Silicon Chip?

Tags: apple-m1, rosetta, raptor

I tried running it by forcing it to run by Rosetta but sadly the option isn't visible. I need it to complete one of my classes in college.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up checking it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested Raptor on my MacBook Pro M1. 8/17

Raptor (8/17/22) is an Intel only application. You must have Rosetta installed to run the application.

When you attempt to run your first Intel only application you will be prompted to install.
[image: diaglog]

Click Install. The system will request your user name and password to complete.

Once Rosetta is installed, you need only run the application:

[image: working]